# Music player seek bar in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am currently working on an audio streaming mobile using Ionic 3, html, js and CSS. I was wondering if there's any plugin I could use that would allow me to have custom made music controls, including the interface and seek bar... The ones like ionic-audio already have their and it doesn't look very nice, or is there a way to manipulate these? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use SASS(CSS) to style ionic-audio component as you like. Check [ionic-audio.scss](https://github.com/arielfaur/ionic-audio/blob/3.0/src/ionic-audio.scss) at source to know which clases uses and change them on your page.scss